# Cannot cast from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I've a two fragments defined in the layout of my `MainActivity` and set by `setContentView`. I'd like to call some methods from these fragments, but I don't know how to acces them. Eclipse says: "Cannot cast form Fragment to ListFileFrgament".

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FileListFragment listFragment = (FileListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.list_fragment);  
     // cannot casr here
    PlayerFragment playerFragment = (PlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.player_fragment); 
     // cannot cast here
    }


}
```

Comment: check your layout file. Check your IDs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your imports match - it may be that FileListFragment / PlayerListFragment extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment while getFragmentManager().findFragmentById returns android.app.Fragment.

Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` to return android.support.v4.app.Fragment instances.